# Displaying .gdb content(Feature classes) in winidows forms

Tags: arcobjects

I am having a .gdb file(World.gdb). I want to display or i want to see the content of this gdb file in winForms programmatically(C#). How can i do it?
I dont want to view via ArcCatalog.

Please help soon.

Regards,
Arun

Comment: Are you just trying to display the attributes (feature class names, feature count, etc) in the form or display the actual shape like the Preview tab in ArcCatalog?

Comment: I am performing geoprocessing tools (buffer analysis) on featureclasses. I just want to see whether gp.Execute() method has created output Featureclass or no? and for that i dont want to use ArcCatalog.

Comment: You could use the IGPUtilities.Exists method, which returns whether the object referred to by the given geoprocessing value object exists.

Answer (score 3):

I find it handy to put [IName](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00420000014r000000)s in a Dictionary. Opening only open the featureclass when it is needed. Getting a list of INames is much less costly than getting a list of references to featureclasses (or tables).

```
public static Dictionary<string, IName> GetNames(IWorkspace ws)
{
    var outDict = new Dictionary<string, IName>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    IEnumDatasetName enumDSname = ws.get_DatasetNames(esriDatasetType.esriDTAny);
    if (enumDSname == null)
        return outDict;

    enumDSname.Reset();
    IDatasetName dsn;
    while ((dsn = enumDSname.Next()) != null)
    {
        outDict.Add(dsn.Name, (IName)dsn);
        var fdsn = dsn as IFeatureDatasetName;
        if (dsn is IFeatureDatasetName)
        {
            var enumDSname2 = dsn.SubsetNames;
            if (enumDSname2 != null)
            {
                IDatasetName dsn2;
                while ((dsn2 = enumDSname2.Next()) != null)
                {
                    outDict.Add(dsn2.Name, (IName)dsn2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return outDict;
}
```

Also, Esri recommends using Activator to instantiate the workspacefactory.

```
public static IWorkspace OpenWS(string gdbPath)
{
    var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory");
    var wsf = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(gdbPath))
        throw new Exception("directory not found: " + gdbPath);
    if (!wsf.IsWorkspace(gdbPath))
        throw new Exception("not really a file gdb: " + gdbPath);
    return wsf.OpenFromFile(gdbPath, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since file geodatabase is a proprietary format, you need to use Esri tools or other software (for example, [FME](http://blog.safe.com/2011/08/file-geodatabase-gets-more-open-reflections-on-esris-file-geodatabase-api/)) that has embedded this format.

Meantime, you are welcome to try the [File GDB API](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geodatabases/10.0/file-gdb-api) Esri has released some time ago.

Answer (score -1):

You can get feature class names from the .gdb file using IWorkspace interface, if you want to get get all feature class names. Then check if your desire feature class is present here or not.

Code is not tested

**EDIT**

```
List<string> GetAllDatasetNames(string gdbFilePath)
{
     IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactory()
     IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile (gdbFilePath, 0);
     IEnumDataset enumDataset = workspace.get_Datasets(esriDatasetType.esriDTAny);
     List<string> names = new List<string>();
     IDataset dataset = null;
     while((dataset = enumDataset.Next())!= null)
     {
          names.Add(dataset.Name);
     }
     return names;
}
```

Comment: As I wrote the full code here, there can be some error. So dont copy-paste please

Comment: This will not include names of things inside of a featuredataset.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall But the question does not ask for things inside feature dataset. It asks for things inside gdb. In that sense my answer is not wrong

Comment: If a featureclass is inside of a featuredataset which is inside a gdb, then the featureclass is in the gdb.